# itext Invalid font type, Font file file:/C:....ttf not found

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to load a specific font in my itext pdf. But I keep getting an error. 
The logo.png and OpenSans-Bold.ttf are in the same folder. But if I try to run the code, the font file can not be found at location C:/somepatch/core/target/classes/OpenSans-Bold.ttf. But If i look at that folder, the file is there.

```
 private static final String LOGO_LOCATION = PdfBuilder.class.getClassLoader().getResource("logo.png").toString();
 private static final String FONT_FS_JOEY_BOLD = PdfBuilder.class.getClassLoader().getResource("OpenSans-Bold.ttf").toString();
```

I've also tried googeling the problem and some say I need to use getResourceAsStream. So I use:

```
private static final String FONT_FS_JOEY_BOLD = PdfBuilder.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("OpenSans-Bold.ttf").toString();
```

This gives me a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid font type.

There is noting wrong with the fonts because

```
private static final String FONT_FS_JOEY_BOLD = "./src/main/resources/fonts/fs_joey-bold-webfont.ttf";
```

works. Unfotunately I can not use this method because I need to build the pdf in different packages. (and I really want to know wat is going wrong with the first two examples)

Comment: Please have a look at [**this**](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/examples-font-tutorial#15-f03_embedded.java)

Comment: Tried it like that. Gave me the same error.

    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("src\\main\\resources\\fonts\\OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf","Cp1250", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

works inside the first class but not in my second class. That is why i wanted to find the file from the classpath.